# Spring boot - Bad Request when sending a big number at json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

If I send a number with 10 digits Spring accept my request, but if I send a number with more than 10 digits Spring return status 400 (Bad request).
I configured Jackson to accept receive fields at json without quotes, I need this behavior for numbers.

So when I send for example:
{
"number": 12345678912
}

I always receive status 400

Comment: I'm not an expert but perhaps the problem comes when you parse the number. Maybe, you would need a BigInteger.

Comment: You simply failed to mention which data-type you are using, which happens to be critical information when you are dealing with buffer-overflow of variables.

Comment: Not an expert either, but it's probably expecting an int, which should be smaller than 2^31 (2147483648) or at the very best, a unsigned int, which should be smaller than 2^32 (4294967296). Anything bigger than that will not fit.

Comment: What data type are you using ?

Comment: add more details and code samples

Comment: I'm using Long ant my entity, but at Swagger alway's appear integer at this field.

Comment: have u got the answer?........i have got the same problem......please share with me if you have found a solution